# How can I migrate aws postgres 9.5 to postgres 12.7?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, upgrade, migrate

I am using Amazon Web Services RDS Postgres 9.5.
It is quite old and I want to know how should I upgrade to Postgres 12.7 ?

Is there a way to back it up in Postgres 9.5 and restore it to Postgres 12.7 ?
(Can this be done within AWS itself ?)

Thanks.

Comment: I can't comment on the upgrade path, but we've dumped PG 9.3 databases and restored them to 11.9 RDS systems with no problem. (Well actually there are SQL changes between 9.3 and some higher version, I think 9.6 though I tested 9.3 vs 10, which can make the SQL code invalid and restore fail, but assuming these differences have been addressed in your source database then I'd expect a dump/restore from 9.6 to 12.7 to work.)

Comment: [Upgrading the PostgreSQL DB engine for Amazon RDS - Amazon Relational Database Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_UpgradeDBInstance.PostgreSQL.html#USER_UpgradeDBInstance.PostgreSQL.MajorVersion)

Comment: @404 can you recommend how you dump and restore the PG database for 9.3 to 11.9. I think maybe that would help. I tried with pgadmin on local, somethings seems to fail so I want to know how did you do this backup and restore process. Thanks.

Comment: @Axil Depends what the failure is. It's been a while since I've done it, but I think one potential issue is using a lower version of pg_dump to backup and then a higher version of pg_restore to restore (or vice versa), it gives an error about the version of the dump I think. Solution is to use the same version to dump/restore (higher version of pg_dump should be able to dump older database fine). Or if the error is about some invalid SQL syntax then that may be due to the changes in some SQL interpretation that occurred around 9.6. It really just depends on what the exact error is.

Comment: As for how we did the actual dump/restore, just a simple dump with custom output type selected, can do either via pgadmin or the pg_dump/restore executables. We've done this quite a few times and it's worked fine, but if you tell me the specific error you're encountering I may be able to give more precise advice.

Comment: I tried to backup with pgadmin 4.29, after 198 seconds it has Failed (exit code 1). It generated about 96.5 MB of backup.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/axilaris/ccebb004f9f749a6acff0a527db7dcfd, i did then from command line, it shows "query failed: ERROR:  permission denied for relation topology"

Comment: @Axil That's a "simple" permissions issue. It sounds like whatever role you're using to perform the dump doesn't have access to either the "topology" schema or the "topology" table within that schema.

Comment: I tried to ask AWS for rdsadmin (which is the superuser), unfortunately they only deal with accounts issue and not technical.  I tried setting topology owner to the master user account that I am using but it still has the same error. Any idea how can you backup fully ? Thanks

Comment: @Axil Use pgadmin logged in as the role performing the backup to browse to that schema. If you can access it, try and access that table. One of those accesses should fail. Have a look at the schema or table in the sql tab or its properties to see which role owns that table and what other roles might have access to it. From memory so maybe not 100%, the owner should be able to access it in all cases, and other roles may or may not also have access. The "backup" role (which may be the "near-superuser" created initially) needs access to all schemas/tables in order to be able to back them up.

Comment: Mind you, this is still just the dump -> restore option. There may be ways to upgrade PG in place, so have a look into whether that can be done as well.